# Add TTS functionality to Dart console app

Tags: dart, command-line-interface, text-to-speech

can I get some pointers on how to add Text To Speech functionality to a console/CLI app. I have tried packages for Flutter but I get this error 'Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'. I am assuming they expect a user interface.

I am pretty much a novice, would be glad answers do not assume too much on my side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Flutter is all about UI whereas a command line app has no UI.

They dont have anything to do with eachother except that Dart is the language used by Flutter.

Flutter tts plugins depend on the specific tts implementation embedded in the OS that the plugin will be running on — Android / IOS, etc.

A Dart command line tool runs in a VM and is OS-independent.

So, as far as I know, it is impossible to import a Flutter plugin into a Dart command line app and then compile it.

The only way I can see to get tts functionality in a Dart command line tool is to use a web based (OS-independent) tts service such as the [Google text to speech API](https://jeffmcmorris.medium.com/dart-flutter-command-line-google-text-to-speech-api-tutorial-6b70e16c9075).